# Ubuntu 18.04 does not boot after installing WineHQ and Lutris

Tags: boot, wine, power-management

[image]

[edited for claryfing some details]

I installed Lutris (utility for running games designed for windows) and Winehq (required for it) and after reboot the system got stuck in "record successful boot for GRUB" (see image)

When I boot, I see the GRUB menu for choosing Ubuntu / Ubuntu recovery mode / Windows / etc. Then if leave the normal startup begin, the system gets stuck as above, but if I enter in the recovery mode and request to keep normal startup (without actually doing anything else) then the system boots apparently fine, apart from some details that do not work properly (I had to change the scale of the display, and the laptop does no longer suspend when closing the lid, in addition some of the Fn keys like brightness do not work anymore -- BTW it is a Thinkpad X1 carbon 5th gen). 
I tried to fix packages via dpkg in the recovery mode it but does not help.

Now the question is what did I broke when installing winehq/wine/lutris. I had to enable i386 architecture and add several repositories, which I already deleted (anything related with i386/wine/winehq/lutris...)

It seems that Lutris/wine has messed up some graphics driver or power manager or whatever, but I do not find similar problems reported. Has anyone any idea of what has been broken and how can I fix it?

Comment: Read your second question before this, there is a Ubuntu Game ISO(see google) that has everything on it you would want for games.  It would be another boot partition so it would not messed up your primary Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks crip659. The issue is that when doing that installation it seems I have already messed up several things: the brightness controls do not work anymore, also closing the lid does no longer suspend the laptop, and I have tried some tips to fix that but do not succeed (however I did fix the boot issue by adding nomodeset to the Grub file). I would like to avoid reinstalling just because I do not want to again start installing all my programs etc. I should maybe create a more detailed question with the graphics issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after trying to install wine. I removed and reinstalled wine but didn't change anything. Using nomodeset stopped brightness control from working. I was able to fix it finally.

Boot with nomodeset and open Terminal. Then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt upgrade
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Remove nomodeset from grub and save.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

That's all. Everything should be fine after this.

Comment: It is true, I also lost my brightness controller. Although I don't gave to follow nomodeset based booting, recovery Linux boot worked.