# reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 does not show option keep files

Tags: 18.04, reinstall

I want to reinstall Linux 18.04 on my laptop after I screwed up several things (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209133/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-boot-after-installing-winehq-and-lutris), also help is welcome with that), but when I boot with the USB live I don't see the option for keeping the files (I don't want to format again).
I am not sure if this has something to do with the fact that the system in the laptop is version 18.04.4 and the one in USB is 18.04.3.
Can anyone confirm if this is the issue and if so whether it can be solved with an iso of version 18.04.4, and where could I find it?

Comment: Version 18.04.4 can be found here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/bionic/daily-live/current/

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall without reformatting, you need to select "Something else" between the installation options. This brings you to the manual partitioning screen. There, you have to indicate yourself which partitions are to be used, and doing so, you can uncheck the "Format" checkbox to prevent the installer from reformatting prior to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, will that keep all the stuff in /home/ ? Note that I don't have separe partitions for the home and root. Also, I have dual boot with Windows. Will that screw up the dual boot somehow?

Comment: If data is important to you, would recommend backing up first.  Bad stuff can happen to data you don't want to lose.  Dual boot should not be affected.

Comment: Indeed, it will keep your entire current configuration intact, and preserve all your data. Nevertheless, as crip659 indicated, you must have an up to date backup before proceeding